# Skip the test in TestNG and run tests via pom.xml use maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm writing test in Java using TestNG and run tests via pom.xml file use maven-surefire-plugin.

If I skip the `@BeforeTest` method then it skip and count all annotations methods in my class file.

How it possible to skip the test inside the class file and it count only `@Test` methods not all of annotations?

[image]

Comment: If you use `@BeforeTest` the method will be executed before any test method which is annotated with `@Test`. And if you have four test methods for each method the `@BeforeTest` method will be called which skips and this will result in the number four of skipped tests ? What is the real problem?

Comment: But why it shows 4 skipped tests not only 2 ?

Comment: _*ApplicationTableTempl.java_ isn't saved. Did you have 4 tests before starting the last editing?

Comment: I'm just running ApplicationTableTempl.java class via POM as Maven test where are 4 methods: BeforeTest Test Test AfterTest, and if skipped the BeforeTest method it count all this methos: BeforeTest Test Test AfterTest = 4 skipped tests. But if run as testNG then I got 2 skipped tests.

Comment: You have "4" because the test reporter of surefire doesn't take care of configuration methods and count them as test methods.